# Which git command is used to display comments mentioned by a reviewer for code review in Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a use case where I want to know through git bash command that what a reviewer has commented for my code that was sent for code review.Can anybody suggest which Git command can solve my request?

Comment: Code reviews are not a feature of Git directly, so there is no such command. This is built on top of Git by the Bitbucket service. But maybe they have an API for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native Git command, only [GitHub commands through their cli](https://cli.github.com/)

For instance:

- [`gh pr status`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_status) would display the status associated to the PR
- [`gh pr view`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_view) would view a PR (but not the latest comments)